# How do you use the expression "to blow a fuse"?

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms-in-context

How do you use the expression "to blow a fuse" in the literal sense in sentences?

For example: To make sure the fuses don't blow, or "go off", or what?
Did a fuse "blow"?

Answer (score 2):

***[To blow a fuse:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+a+fuse)***

> to burn out the fuse on an electrical circuit and lose power.
>
> - *The microwave oven blew a fuse, so we had no power. You'll blow a fuse
>   if you use too many appliances at once.*

> To suddenly lose power due to an overloaded electrical circuit.
>
> - *Well, we just blew a fuse—it seems that running the space heater, the coffee maker, and a blow dryer at the same time was not the best idea!*

(The Free Dictionary)